# Make a single line with elements be last one on next line but not full-width?

Tags: css

I have three links in a row, and I want the third one to be on the next line, and normally I would use

```
 .new-line { display:block; }
```

But if I do that, the link is 100% the width of the next line and if you move your mouse on the line, you will see all of it is clickable (even if not hovering over the actual word link).

And in this case, I also have content in the :before that needs to appear inline with the actual content of the link.

So it is:

```
.new-line:before { content: 'something'; }
```

I am not able to add extra mark up (HTML nor jQuery) in this example.

Is there a way with CSS to make the third element be on the next line?

Here is a JSFIDDLE with the exact markup that I am trying to achieve this.

http://jsfiddle.net/2Fkev/3/

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
.new-line:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
}
```

Let me know if it's useful.

Comment: Thanks for the help Joaquin, that does help, except I forgot to mention I already have some :before, but I had a span, so I moved my current before to the span and using your solution, it worked! THANKS :)

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely solve your problem, but check for the compatibility issues

```
.new-line {display:table-cell; }
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Fkev/5/)

If you can allow yourself, the perfect solution would be:

```
a{
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
}

.new-line { clear:both; }
```